# Кастомная TreeModel

Tags: java, javascript

Всем привет. Пишу свою собственную реализацию TreeModel, и возник вопрос:
для того, чтобы создать TreeModelEvent (для fireTreeNodesInserted), нужно в него передать TreePath. Откуда его брать?

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreePath.html

Comment: Нужно руками при каждом добавлении элемента в дерево для него создавать TreePath?